# Set USB Drives to mount at specific file location

Tags: pi-3, usb

I have a Python program I've been working on with the Raspberry Pi.  Currently, I am trying to create an Update Module that I can use to update my software without having to manually transfer updated files (There will be multiple Pi's running my software).

I am trying to setup the Pi so that whenever a USB Storage device is plugged in, it will be mapped to a specific file location.  For example, right now, if I plug a USB Storage Device into one of the Pi's USB Ports, the data is in the `/media/pi/62144E65144E3C73` folder.  How would I set it up so that it would instead map to something like `/media/pi/usb_data`?  Is it possible to set it up so it would map any USB storage device to this location?

I'd like to set it up so that any USB Storage device can be used without having to format it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer... will probably morph into longer answer when I get to test it...

To mount a USB storage device in a predictable manner, you can use `udev rules`

ArchLinux has a terrific write-up on [udev rule creation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev).  And [Writing udev rules: Daniel Drake](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#example-usbhdd) should be helpful when attempting to predictable mount USB storage devices.